# tt_news: "Don't display first image in single view" (firstImageIsPreview) doesn't work

Tags: typo3, tt-news

I\ve set the following options in the news module:

- Don't display first image in single view (firstImageIsPreview)
- Don't display first image in single view (forceFirstImageIsPreview) even when only one image is available

but still, the articles display the first image in single view. Doesn't matter if I use 1 or more photos. I use version 4.7.2 (current latest). Where is the problem?

Comment: What news extension are you using? `tt_news`? And what is the version of the extension?

Comment: @pgampe, yes tt_news, v3.2.1, as bundled with 4.7.2. Everything downloaded yesterday.

Comment: You should switch to `news` if you can. The last real update for `tt_news` was done for `TYPO3 4.5`. After that, only updates to fix complete crashes have been done. Other than that, please double check your TS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to clear the FE cache? Then I remember that the single view uses a html template hence you can delete the html for the image or when you can delete the TS for the image?

Comment: Hi Chiyou, thanks for answer.I don't understand what you say in 2nd sentence, especially the "TS for the image"...

Comment: I've tried to clear the TYPO3 cache by clicking the lightning icon in the top right corner of the screen, but the problem persists.